# ErrorCode: BadRequest_InvalidBlob

Tags: azure-data-explorer

we are using Kusto to collect metrics on Bing magnetar platform and it had been working well for months. But we can't find any metrics from Jun.5 to Jun.19 and the ingestion failure shows details like:

`BadRequest_InvalidBlob: hr: '2161770498' 'expected value at line 1 column 4117'`

The issue surfaced and was mitigated without any changes from our side. Anyone sharing thoughts on how to further investigate the issue would be appreciated.

PS. the cluster is: 'adsdata.eastus.kusto.windows.net'

I've tried below command, but I'd like to how to continue the investigation.

.show ingestion failures

Comment: Hello Charly.
We had some issues with JSON ingestion recently related to Infinity/NaN values, which are not part of JSON standard. Could you please attach sample JSON file somewhere (or send it to my MS email address), so we can confirm it is the same issue?

Comment: @Michael, shared ingested json as below, Would you please have a look? 

`{"server":"Charly-PC","loadTime":"2022-12-01 04:00:00.607","value":101,"Name":"TestLogValueWithCustomLoadTime"}`